# Wordpress Conflict with 2 plugins concerning function get_query_var and WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I have a conflict with 2 plugins : Dokan Lite and AwesomeSupport

The error message : "Call to a member function get() on null"

The conflict is between the function get_query_var in Dokan Lite plugin who is called first :
https://github.com/wp-plugins/dokan-lite/blob/master/classes/rewrites.php#L227

Who get broken by the other plugin :
https://github.com/Awesome-Support/Awesome-Support/blob/develop/includes/functions-post.php#L514

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
This line seems breaking connection with the call of get_query_var from the Dokan plugin.

But I don't know what to do to resolve this problem ?

Bellow you can see the backtrace :

```
Call to a member function get() on null
Backtrace from Exception
In /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/query.php [line 28]:

/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/classes/rewrites.php [line 240] calling get_query_var()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 298] calling store_query_filter()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 515] calling do_action()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php [line 1683] calling do_action_ref_array()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php [line 3248] calling get_posts()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php [line 3357] calling query()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/awesome-support/includes/functions-post.php [line 514] calling __construct()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/awesome-support/includes/admin/functions-misc.php [line 344] calling wpas_get_tickets()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 298] calling wpas_request_first_5star_rating()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php [line 323] calling apply_filters()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php [line 453] calling do_action()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-settings.php [line 325] calling do_action()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-config.php [line 107] calling require_once()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-load.php [line 37] calling require_once()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/admin.php [line 31] calling require_once()
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/edit.php [line 10] calling require_once()
```

------ edit -------

Ok, i think I understand a bit more, here is what i think :

The problem is this line in dokan-lite/classes/rewrites.php : 
`$author = get_query_var( $this->custom_store_url );`

The AwesomeSupport plugin create a new WP_QUERY with specific args just before the get_query_var call in awesome-support/includes/functions-post.php : 
`$query = new WP_Query( $args );`

So there is no more existing var thats why it return null value.

My temporary solution is to add a new function to check if wp_query var exist in dokan-lite/classes/rewrites.php :

```
function qv_isset($var_name) {
    $array = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;
    return array_key_exists($var_name, $array);
}
```

Then I use it to check if the var exist :

```
if ( $this->qv_isset($this->custom_store_url) ) {
    $author = get_query_var( $this->custom_store_url );
} else { $author = ""; }
```

I don't know if my solution is enough or good.
If you can confirm that's the best way...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best solution.

It's just by adding a priority to the filter who use this function :

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'store_query_filter' ), 99 );
```

That's it...